# Start of the week on Monday in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, dayofweek, spark3

This is my dataset:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as F
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([('2021-02-07',),('2021-02-08',)], ['date']) \
    .select(
        F.col('date').cast('date'),
        F.date_format('date', 'EEEE').alias('weekday'),
        F.dayofweek('date').alias('weekday_number')
    )
df.show()
#+----------+-------+--------------+
#|      date|weekday|weekday_number|
#+----------+-------+--------------+
#|2021-02-07| Sunday|             1|
#|2021-02-08| Monday|             2|
#+----------+-------+--------------+
```

[`dayofweek`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.dayofweek.html#pyspark.sql.functions.dayofweek) returns weekday numbers which start on Sunday.

Desired result:

```
+----------+-------+--------------+
|      date|weekday|weekday_number|
+----------+-------+--------------+
|2021-02-07| Sunday|             7|
|2021-02-08| Monday|             1|
+----------+-------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
F.expr('weekday(date) + 1')
```

[`weekday`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#weekday)

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as F
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([('2021-02-07',),('2021-02-08',)], ['date']) \
    .select(
        F.col('date').cast('date'),
        F.date_format('date', 'EEEE').alias('weekday'),
        F.expr('weekday(date) + 1').alias('weekday_number'),
    )
df.show()
#+----------+-------+--------------+
#|      date|weekday|weekday_number|
#+----------+-------+--------------+
#|2021-02-07| Sunday|             7|
#|2021-02-08| Monday|             1|
#+----------+-------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```py
date_format(col("date"), "u")).alias('weekday_number')
```

For some reason, it's not in the [Spark's documentation of datetime patterns for formatting](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html)

You also might need  to add this configuration line:
`spark.conf.set('spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy', 'LEGACY')`

Thanks for your feedback and very happy to help =)

Comment: I have upvoted, but I cannot accept the answer, because of two reasons. 1. Using Spark 3+ I am forced to use "LEGACY" configuration which is likely to be discontinued later. 2. In my real case, I already use "spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy" configuration, but with another value, so I cannot use both configurations at the same time...

Comment: No problem, the most important is that it helps =)